# How to use Caffe library in C++ project with CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use Caffe in my C++ project which I compile with CMakeLists.txt, but it doesn't want to work. My only line in the code is

```
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>
```

I compiled Caffe myself, it is installed in the directory "/home/tamas/caffe". My CMakeLists.txt looks like this so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
include(FindPkgConfig)

project (main)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -pthread")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")
set (OpenCV_DIR "/home/tamas/opencv/include/opencv2")
set (Caffe_DIR "/home/tamas/caffe")

file (GLOB source_files "${source_dir}/ssd_video.cpp")

find_package(OpenCV 4.4.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (main ${source_files})

target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(main ${Caffe_LIBRARIES})
```

The error is the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCaffe.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Caffe", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Caffe" with any of
  the following names:

    CaffeConfig.cmake
    caffe-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Caffe" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Caffe_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Caffe"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The problem is that I have searched and I don't have a FindCaffe.cmake file on my computer. I found an example for CaffeConfig.cmake, but I tried it and it doesn't work either.

Is there a way I can link Caffe with my C++ project? Thanks!

Comment: If everything else fails, you can add your own imported library. Not sure why `CaffeConfig.cmake` did not work, but it may be a good point to start.

Comment: @fabian files such as `CaffeConfig.cmake` should be generated by the build. Don't download another one as OP suggest, as it may not be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue you may do the following:

1. Download this [FindCAFFE.cmake](https://github.com/mhauskn/dqn/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindCAFFE.cmake) file
2. Create `cmake` dir in your repo root directory and put the downloaded file there.
3. Modify your CMake file:

   - add `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")`
   - change `set (Caffe_DIR "/home/tamas/caffe")` to `set (CAFFE_ROOT_DIR  "/home/tamas/caffe")`
   - change `find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)` to `find_package(CAFFE REQUIRED)`
   - use `CAFFE_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `CAFFE_LIBRARIES` for include directories and link libraries respectively
4. Clean up your build dir and run `cmake` command again

Comment: Thanks for your help, your solution worked! I had to add a bunch of stuff myself though

Comment: @Totemi1324 thanks, could you mark my answer as a solution? And I'm curious what stuff have you added to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about your answer, now your solution is marked. I had to add the following to my CMakeLists.txt: include_directories("/usr/local/cuda/include"); 
include_directories("/usr/include/glog"); target_link_libraries(main "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0" "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so.2.2")

Comment: @Totemi1324 CMake has FindCuda, it would be better to use it instead of setting include/libraries path manually. See https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake

Comment: You're right, thanks. My solution above is more of a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

`<library>_DIR` should not be set manually in CMake code usually. There are better alternatives that should be used as setting these variable won't necessarily do what you want. It won't change where `find_package` finds its libraries.

The `CaffeConfig.cmake` file is generated when building Caffe. You should never download another one, these files are compatible only with a specific build configuration.

The Caffe library supports to be used with CMake, so `FindCaffe.cmake` is unnecessary.

For `find_package` to work, either set the `<package>_ROOT` variable (require CMake 3.12 minimum) or you must append the install path in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Here's a CMake example that uses the prefix path:

```
# If you only built the library
list (APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/tamas/caffe/build-dir")

# If you installed the library there
list (APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/tamas/caffe/")

find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)
```

Note that the `Caffe_LIBRARIES` and `Caffe_INCLUDE_DIRS` won't be set. This is old CMake style and the Caffe library uses the new style. This is what you should do:

```
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC caffe caffeproto)
```

This line add **both** include directory and adds linking to the libraries too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried both possibilities you provided, but I got the same error. Maybe I didn't understand something, but in my Caffe folder, there are no FindCaffe.cmake and CaffeConfig.cmake files.

Comment: Usually, in the Caffe directory you should find it containing `lib/cmake/Caffe/CaffeConfig.cmake` when typing `find_package(Caffe REQUIRED)`, CMake will try to find this path.

Comment: @Totemi1324 if there is no such file anywhere, I would recommend compile it from source using CMake. When you set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and install the library, you can then append it to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for CMake to find it.